# History of Infinity: How does the idea of infinite set become widely accepted?

Tags: mathematicians, infinity

It seems pretty strange to me that the idea of infinity and infinite sets was initially opposed by many prominent Mathematicians, even driving Cantor into depression. However, in modern days, everyone seems to accept infinity without any problem, despite the existence of many paradoxes like the Banach-Tarski paradox and the prisoner hat paradoxes.

I understand that modern Mathematics is largely built on the concept of infinity, and Mathematics has already become a "game of ideal world," and I am not here to oppose the idea. What I am confused about is that historically once upon a time the majority of Mathematicians opposed the idea (at a time where Mathematics was not yet built on infinity), even driving Cantor himself into craziness. It seems pretty strange to me why and how the world has changed to this current state, where anyone opposing the idea is labeled a "crank".

Comment: Who exactly opposed the idea of infinity at the time of Cantor? Afik, people opposed to his set theory on different grounds, not on his usages of infinite sets?

Comment: Also, "modern Mathematics is largely built on the concept of infinity" is not quite right. Most of modern math uses set theory and infinite sets (not "infinity" which is ill-defined) are prominent features of ST that very few working mathematicians object to.

Comment: The idea of set is much younger than the idea of infinity.

Comment: Citing from Cantor page from Wikipedia, "his work encountered too much opposition for that to be possible", "Kronecker, ..., became increasingly uncomfortable with the prospect of having Cantor as a colleague, perceiving him as a "corrupter of youth" for teaching his ideas to a younger generation of mathematicians", "But in 1885, Mittag-Leffler was concerned about the philosophical nature and new terminology in a paper Cantor had submitted to Acta." At least for me, it seems pretty clear that his idea of infinite set was not popular during the time.

Comment: My question is not focused on "Mathematics is built on infinity" part, but the part "very few working mathematicians object to infinite sets" as you points out. This was not true during Cantor's time and even today it can be counter-intuitive if thought carefully. My question is why people have chosen the way it is today, that prefer "usefulness" over "intuition." It seems to me historically mathematicians preferred "intuition" more.

Comment: What I mean is, say for example "earth is flat vs. earth is a sphere" has a very clear answer and a firm evidence can overturn a previously popular idea. However whether to use the "infinite set theory" is a pure opinion based thing and there is no objective evidence. It solely depends on what framework people choose to work with. And the fact a previously popular idea was overturned (by Cantor's initially unpopular idea) seems very surprising to me.

Comment: Cantor's theory incorporated infinite sets and worked much better in analysis and algebra than its predecessors. It also answered traditional objections, like the "annihilation of the finite" in arithmetic. This is no more pure opinion or less objective and "firm" than Copernican system explaining astronomical data better than Ptolemaic, or calculus serving mechanics better than traditional geometry, or predicate logic being more expressive than Aristotelian. [Measuring the Size of Infinite Collections by Mancosu](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1755020309990128) is a good historical sketch.

Comment: Thank you. Seems pretty close to what I am looking for.

Comment: As I said, people objected to Cantor’s set theory, but it was not due to his use of infinite sets. The objection was to his level of abstraction. Infinite objects, not yet called sets, were widely used since introduction of  Calculus. I think, your real question is about acceptance of Cantor’s set theory, not the idea of infinity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Many mathematicians were uncomfortable with Cantor exactly for *his* use of infinite sets. While it was still possible to imagine that calculus only needed Aristotle's potential infinity, or at least keep the difference out of view, Cantor endorsed *actual* infinity head on. That, and the manner of producing higher transfinites based on it, became a point of concern for proto-intuitionists like Kronecker, Poincare, Lebesgue, etc., who did not complain about his level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting numerous sources,

> The German physicist Max Planck said that science advances one funeral
> at a time. Or more precisely: “A new scientific truth does not triumph
> by convincing its opponents and making them see the light, but rather
> because its opponents eventually die, and a new generation grows up
> that is familiar with it.”

That's not 100% applicable here, since mathematics simply accepts anything which results from a valid proof.  Remember that math does not necessarily hew to the physical world, so the existence of "infinities" of different measure is perfectly acceptable, just as is nonEuclidean geometry,  the Cantor set, and the Discrete Metric, to name some famous examples.

Comment: "math does not necessarily hew to the physical world," this viewpoint was not common once upon a time. I know it is the way it is now, but historically it seemed more probable to become a different universe where Mathematics is built on a more real-world based framework.

Answer (score -2):

It's not that surprising when all things are considered. Most people do not like their cherished ideas over-turned. Take, for instance, calculus.  Newton expected opposition to his new ideas, which is why he couched his discoveries not in calculus, but in the mathematical language of the day:  Euclidean geometry. Given his mathematical sophistication, no doubt he actually enjoyed coming up with geometric proofs of what he discovered by use of the calculus.

Set theory was still a new idea when Cantor came up with his new theory of the infinite. So for most mathematicians, this was newness piled upon newness - so probably one newness too many. Still, most mathematicians came round to Cantor's point of view, since his reasoning was sound. The main problem with it is that it is a theory with very few real applications.

In other words, it's widely accepted but also widely useless.